# how to validate same form id in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to validate two forms with same id. for first its working fine. but for second its not validating why?
Here, i have given the example code:

```
function cc(id){
    if(document.getElementById(id).value.toUpperCase()==(id)){
        document.getElementById(id).style.backgroundColor = "green";
    }else{
       document.getElementById(id).style.backgroundColor = "red";
    }
}

<form id="save"  method="post">
<input type="text" name="A"  id="C" class="textbox" onKeyUp="cc(id,this, 'H')"  maxlength="1"  />
<input type="text" name="A"  id="C" class="textbox" onKeyUp="cc(id,this, 'H')"  maxlength="1"  />
</form>
```

http://jsbin.com/viraqixicigi/6/edit

Comment: IDs should be unique

Comment: "trying to validate two forms with same id" — Don't. IDs must be unique.

Comment: Since you pass `this` as an argument, why do you need to use `getElementById()`. Also, you're not setting `id` before you pass it as an argument.

Comment: that's what i am doing. but, it is not validating. you can check it in link @Quentin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `this` argument to operate on the target of the event:

```
function cc(element, goodValue){
    if(element.value.toUpperCase() == goodValue){
        element.style.backgroundColor = "green";
    }else{
        element.style.backgroundColor = "red";
    }
}

<form id="save"  method="post">
<input type="text" name="A"  id="C" class="textbox" onKeyUp="cc(this, 'H')"  maxlength="1"  />
<input type="text" name="A"  id="C" class="textbox" onKeyUp="cc(this, 'H')"  maxlength="1"  />
</form>
```

[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/sujusiruvesu/1/edit)